# Display (polish) characters properly

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding, polish

I'm reading an xml-file which contains german, french, spanish, english and polish text.

To handle the polish letters (which caused the most trouble) i tried to do it like this:

```
File file = new File(path);
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(is, charset);

InputSource src = new InputSource(reader);
src.setEncoding(charset.name());

SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();

saxParser.parse(src, handler);
```

The problem i encountered was that none of the default charsets display the text properly. Some have questionmarks in it some have a combination of other chars in it e.g. ÄÖ..

To break it a bit down I wrote another snippet to test which charset works:

```java
public static void main(String[] args){
        Charset charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
        String chars = "śłuna długie";
        System.out.println(new String(chars.getBytes(charset), charset));
}
```

Again tested every single one but nothing works..
I hope you've got an idea.

Comment: In your first code snippet you don't output anything so it is hard to tell what is happening. The second code snippet works, `śłuna długie` is correcty printed to the console. What console do you use? *Where* do you try to print this text? Does the output device support the characters you want to print?

Comment: It's kind of difficult to provide the right code of a parser because there are so many important parts of it..
Ok, so the problem could be my console.. haven't thought of that. 
It's the default console of my Intellij IDEA

Comment: changed my project and ide encoding to utf 8 and it worked.. thanks buddy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution: Change the encoding of your ide

I used the default encoding of my ide (intellij) which was "windows-1252", due to the fact that I'm using windows on this pc.

So I changed it to UTF-8 and the short test code worked fine for me.